# How to apply vector drawable to an image programmatically?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a bunch of SVG images(5) that I've converted to vector drawables in Android Studio. 
I need to hardcode them in my adapter but I can't figure out how to apply.

Using a regular image(a .png or jpg) this is how I would put them in an array.

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.image_one.png,R.drawable.image_two.png};
```

and apply to the image like below:

```
imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
```

how can I achieve the same with vector drawables(the extension file ends with .xml)

Answer (score 1):

Using getResources() method as follows

```
imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_one));
```

Comment: How do you manage to compile that?  getDrawable returns a Drawable, not a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Both png drawables and vector drawables can be set like this:

1. Say, on file system your drawable is `hello.xml` or `hello.png`
2. You set it like `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello)` in both cases (you don't have to specify extensions)

I would recommend using @DrawableRes annotation next to your type definition, for better compiler checks (`@DrawableRes int [] images = ...`)